# NodeODM options to generate Ultra high quality orthophoto

Tags: opendronemap

In WebODM, when I generate orthophoto I can choose the option "Ultra" for image quality

In the official documentation, there is no mention on how can  I achieve the same using NodeODM API. Does anyone know what is the syntax to get this at NodeODM API?

[image]